# MySQL JOIN Query taking far too long to complete

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a table called users with roughly 250,000 records in it. I have another table called staging with around 75,000 records in it. Staging only has one column, msisdn. I want to check to see how many rows in staging are **not present** in users.

I have the following query, which I have tested on a small data subset, and it seems to work fine:

```
SELECT
    s.*
    FROM staging s
        LEFT OUTER JOIN users u ON u.msisdn=s.msisdn
        WHERE u.msisdn IS NULL
```

The problem however, is when I try to run this query on the full list of 250k users. It ran for an hour before I stopped it. Is there any way I can optimise this query?

I have started running the query on subsets of the data in staging, but this is horribly manual:

```
SELECT
    s.*
    FROM staging s
        LEFT OUTER JOIN users u ON u.msisdn=s.msisdn
        WHERE u.msisdn IS NULL
    LIMIT 0,10000
```

msisdn is the primary key of the staging table, but it's not the primary key of the table users. I don't know if that is significant however.

Comment: Please run your query trough EXPLAIN and post the result. Are both msisdn columns indexed? If so, run OPTIMIZE TABLE on both tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can see what indices MySQL is using with the EXPLAIN command.  Just write `EXPLAIN` in front of your query, and the results will show what index (if any) it's using.  Presumably if it's that slow on so (relatively) small a data set as 250,000 records, it's not exploiting a very effective index, and you'll be able to see where.

It may also help to rewrite the query as a `NOT EXISTS` like so:

```
SELECT s.* FROM staging s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE users.misdn = s.misdn)
```

Answer (score 1):

Put indexes on the `msisdn` columns of each table. Since it's not a PK on `users`, you'll need to put a non-clustered index on it. That should speed up your query tremendously.

Answer (score 1):

Things you can do to speed up this query:

- make sure msisdn is indexed in both tables
- optimize your tables
- replace * with msisdn

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much quicker this will be, but you can try something like.

```
select msisdn
from staging
where msisdn not in (select msisdn from users)
```

Also, make sure that an index exists for the msisdn column in both tables. That should speed things up tremendously.